# Refresh page with ComboBox without refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How can I use a ComboBox to update a .php page without giving refresh?
I have this code that takes the value of the Combo and step it to the page, but doing so reload the page losing the initial search , but I need to pass the value maintaining the previous survey.

Code:

```
<form action="produtos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
 <select name="filtro" id="filtro" onchange="valueselect(this.value);">
   <option value="0">Popularidade</option>
   <option value="1">A-Z</option>
   <option value="2">Z-A</option>
 </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function valueselect(filtro)
{
      window.location.href = "produtos.php?filtro="+filtro;
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function  pesquisa(filtro) {
var id = $("#filtro").val();   
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: produtos.php,
       data: (filtto : id),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
         $('#message')[0].value = filtro
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

But nothing happens.

This is the page in development:
[Page](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1)

Comment: you could pass what variables you want to retain to hidden form fields and retrieve them using the post method when the page refreshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the onchange event of the select you could write javascript to post the form and read the select-option on server side but first do isset($_POST['filtro']) and then write meaningful code inside braces to process the option.

If you want to maintain the state of the select - option across posts, you'll have to write javascript function that sets the selectedIndex of the select option after the page has loaded ( near the closing  tag) and this js will be redered by server on post action and it will output JS to select the appropriate index based on what the user selected. Shall post the code in 2 mins..
Here is the code:

```
<html><body>
<form action="produtos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
 <select name="filtro" id="filtro" >
   <option value="0">Popularidade</option>
   <option value="1">A-Z</option>
   <option value="2">Z-A</option>
 </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
document.getElementById('filtro').onchange=function(){
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}

function setSelected(value){
    var filtro = document.getElementById('filtro');
    var options = filtro.options;
    for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
        if(options[i].value == value){
            filtro.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }   
}
</script> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['filtro'])){
    $selectedValue = $_POST['filtro'];
    // code to process the data
    //...

    // code to remember dropdown
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>setSelected($selectedValue)</script>";


}

?>
</body>
</html>
```